# Netty ChannelFuture timeout when response received

Tags: java, spring, netty, future

I am new in netty I have a tcp client application developed with netty. When i use future get async response from server some response returning but future is not completing into timeout. TCPClient class like following;

```
public TcpClient {
    public boolean connect(Host host) {
        try {
            Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                    .group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 50)
                    .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host.getIp(), host.getPort()))
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
                            socketChannel.config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(2146));
                            FalconClientHandler falconClientHandler = new FalconClientHandler(host);
                            host.setFalconClientHandler(falconClientHandler);
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(falconClientHandler);
                        }
                    });

            channelFuture = clientBootstrap.connect().sync(); //BAŞARI İLE BAĞLANDI

            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();

            return host.isActive();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Connection timed out --> " + e);
            host.setActive(false);
            return false;
        } finally {
            host.setActive(false);
        }
    }

public synchronized ResponseFuture send(long transactionId,String message) {
    final Map<Long,ResponseFuture> responseFuture = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    responseFuture.put(transactionId,new ResponseFuture());
    if (!hostSelector.getUpHostList().isEmpty()) {
        int hostCount = hostSelector.getUpHostList().size();
        Host host;

        host = hostSelector.getUpHostList().get(index.incrementAndGet() % hostCount);
        if (host.isActive()) {
            int headerLength = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(8, 12));
            log.info("[{}] Host {} Tcp Request",message.substring(52, 52 + headerLength),host.getIp());
            channelFuture.addListener((GenericFutureListener<ChannelFuture>) future -> {
                log.info("[{}] Tcp request added to map",transactionId);
                channelFuture.channel().pipeline().get(FalconClientHandler.class).setResponseFuture(responseFuture);
                byte[] byteBuffer = message.getBytes();
                channelFuture.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(byteBuffer));
            });
        }
    } else {
        log.error("AYAKTA HOST YOK");
    }
    return responseFuture.get(transactionId);
}

}
```

Send method have transactionId and request message, When i send this message with transaction id response will return with this thransaction id. I am calling this send like following;

```
    ResponseFuture responseFuture = falconClient.send(Long.valueOf(transactionId), finalMessage);
    try {
        Object obj = responseFuture.get(ddaTimeoutParam, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if(obj!=null) {
            response = obj.toString();
            ddaDelta = System.currentTimeMillis()-ddaRequestStartTime;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        log.warn("[{}] DDA timeout. Timeout parameter: {}",transactionId,ddaTimeoutParam);
        responseFuture.cancel(true);
        response = "TIMEOUT";
        ddaDelta = System.currentTimeMillis()-ddaRequestStartTime;
    }
```

Response future is a basic Future implementation class. Put and get methods like that;

```
public class ResponseFuture implements Future<String> {

    private volatile State state = State.WAITING;
    ArrayBlockingQueue<String> blockingResponse = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);

    private enum State {
        WAITING,
        DONE
    }

    @Override
    public String get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        final String responseAfterWait = blockingResponse.poll(timeout, unit);
        if (responseAfterWait == null) {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        return responseAfterWait;
    }

    public void set(String msg) {
        if (state == State.DONE) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            blockingResponse.put(msg);
            state = State.DONE;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


    My Handler class for receive server response message like following;


public class FalconClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
    private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    private Map<Long,ResponseFuture> responseFuture;

    public synchronized void setResponseFuture(Map<Long,ResponseFuture> responseFuture) {
        log.info("{} ResponseFuture setted",responseFuture.keySet());
        this.responseFuture = responseFuture;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf in) {
        String input = in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        String transactionKey = input.substring(52, 66).trim();
        if(responseFuture.get(Long.valueOf(transactionKey))!=null)
            responseFuture.get(Long.valueOf(transactionKey)).set(input);
        else
            log.info("[{}] Tcp Response map is empty",transactionKey);
        }
}
```

When i run this code under high load like 30 transaction per second, tcp response returned from netty server but future get method received timeout.This situation not occuring every request for example %20 request is fail when 30 tps %50 request fail in 40 tps. What can be occur under load?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible so its hard to aid in this one. One key point is that anything that you process by a EventLoopGroup the threads should never block. Also have you took a look at [netty-closefuture-sync-channel-blocks-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505852/netty-closefuture-sync-channel-blocks-rest-api)

Comment: Since I cannot run your code to test it, how does `send(long transactionId,String message)` react when it is called while another request is already pending, based on the line `.setResponseFuture(responseFuture);`, it would seem like it can only deal with 1 request at the same time

Comment: Thanks for response problem is relevant with future-promise so when this line responseFuture.get(Long.valueOf(transactionKey)).set(input) working before responseFuture.get and inputs are mixing each transaction id. How can i provide only deal with 1 request at time?